# Low consumption build - x64 - Linux

Tags: processor, motherboard, linux, low-cost

I would like to build a low consumption PC that will be on 24/7. It will not be used for intensive calculations of course.

I've already tried some prefabricated solutions like [this one](https://www.amazon.it/SNUNMU-computer-portatile-Supporto-Ethernet/dp/B09FP3GGWS/ref=sr_1_5?__mk_it_IT=%C3%85M%C3%85%C5%BD%C3%95%C3%91&crid=19DKMOT99SHTR&keywords=snumnu+mini+pc+4gb&qid=1652271087&sprefix=snumnu+mini+pc+4gb%2Caps%2C118&sr=8-5) but I found it to be not so elastic (e.g. i've had driver issues under Linux).

So i was thinking about building it by myself starting from spare components. I was thinking about a MoBo, a CPU (with integrated graphics), a PSU and RAM. Is it possibile to build something that will have and avarage consume of 30Watt ? Can someone suggest me some of those piecies?

I've found plenty of build for any kind of purpose (mostly gaming) but really a few for low consumption. And I would like to stay on a x64 architecture (so please don't suggest Raspberry, I've already walked that path ).

Comment: Average 30W would be very low (OC raspberry pi level), but maybe with an undervolted AMD Athlon 3000G, it would be possible

Answer (score 0):

If you want something that is low power consumption and will run 24/7 doing intensive calculations, then you might want to look at an industrial plug computer or embedded controller. It's not a x64 bit install, but I believe [something like this](https://www.icpdas-usa.com/lp_5131) can run a fill linux install.